# I am trying to use DEBUG to find the address of INT 21H using DOS

Tags: cmd, windows-10, dos

I have tried debug in "cmd" as well as using online "PCE.js IBM PC/DOS". 
[image: Command Prompt screenshot]

Comment: debug.com, or debug.exe is not supplied with current versions of Windows.  It was available on workstation versions of Windows up to WinXP.

Comment: @mao `debug.exe` comes with 32-bit versions of Windows 10, just not 64-bit ones.

Comment: @RossRidge, thanks for clarifying

Comment: INT 0x21 is the 8086 software interrupt that was used for DOS system calls. Why do you need that? 64-bit NT uses x64 instructions such as `sysenter` (Intel) or `syscall` (AMD) to efficiently transition to ring 0 and execute a system call. NT system calls are made primarily from functions in two system libraries: ntdll.dll (e.g. `NtCreateFile`) and win32u.dll (e.g. `NtUserCreateWindowEx`). You can get NT debuggers (windbg, cdb, kd, ntsd) by installing the Windows Driver Kit (WDK).